# query only returns document if the mongodb type is string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to get a document with specific student number returned to me with postman. Currently it does not return anything if the student number's type is Int, but if I change it to String, it works as intended. I've only recently started as you probably can see, so please go easy on me

Here is some code

```
app.get("/students/:snumber", function (req, res, next) {
console.log('student number =', req.params.snumber)
next() },

function (req, res, next) {
var query = { student_number: req.params.snumber };

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/uni', function (err, client) {
if (err) throw err
    var db = client.db('uni')
    db.collection('students').find(query).toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err
console.log(result)
res.send(result)
})
})
});
```

{
 "student_number": 1,
 "first_name": "Jeanette",
 "last_name": "Penddreth",
 "email": "jpenddreth0@census.gov",
 "gender": "Female"
}

[Image showing some documents where 1 and 3 are as String & 2 and 4 as Int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3Rlq.png)

Comment: Can you provide the example code and an example document of how it's stored in MongoDB?

Comment: @James Added something that could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL parameters will *always* be set as string therefore `snumber` needs to be converted to an integer i.e.

```
const query = { student_number: parseInt(req.params.snumber, 10) }
```

Comment: Ah, understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Converting value using `Number(v)` or `parseInt(v, 10)` would be enought.
Also, if you want to match both cases, you can wrap it inside `$or`, like:

```js
const query = { $or: [
 { student_number: req.params.snumber },
 { student_number: Number(req.params.snumber) },
] }
```